# How can I add a basic style to my Blogger blog?

Tags: css, blogs, blogger, paragraph

I have a Blogger blog and I wrote a blog entry in the Visual editor. The result looks very cheap: http://ceeprojects.blogspot.hu/2013/10/cee-central-and-eastern-europe.html

I checked the source code of the blog and see that blogger did not inserted a new paragraph after I pressed enters, so the post's source is a mess. In wordpress there are a new paragraph after every enter and a nice space after its last sentence. I tried to add a margin-bottom value to each paragraph, but since my entry doesn't contain them, it was no result.

How can I format my blog now?

Here's the image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/hjv1.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to `blogger`.

Select your Blog,Then go to `Posts`.

Click on `edit` for the post you want to edit.

Then click on "`HTLMl`" next to "compose" at the top left.

You can edit the html of the post here.

[image]